# Windows 7 AHCI mode

Tags: windows-7, windows, pata, ahci

I have installed Windows 7 on drive which was in IDE mode. When I have changed mode to AHCI OS didn't start (I know. AHCI drivers are needed.). Unfortunately when I back to IDE mode, OS still won't start. Computer starts, Windows loading logo apears, but after few seconds it reboots. Probably my OS is corrupted. I tried to use recovery drive, but it didn't find any problems. Fixing MBR also didn't resolve my problem.

Have you got any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Pawel

Comment: You will need to reinstall the operating system and/or use the recovery console.

Comment: Possible dup of http://superuser.com/questions/225189/can-i-change-from-bios-ide-mode-to-ahci-mode-at-any-time. However, I found that it is much easier just to 1) uninstall the current driver, 2) reboot, 3) force install the other version of the driver using the "Have disk" option and 4) reboot to BIOS and change the option. This works 100% of the time with Intel controllers. Even if you missed a reboot, you can always just switch the mode back in BIOS and try again.

Comment: Can you boot into Safe Mode?