# Change SATA mode to AHCI and Windows Fails to boot

Tags: windows-7, pata, ahci

I installed Windows 7 sp1 x64 in IDE mode but I had to change the SATA mode to AHCI; and now Windows 7 failes to boot;

Any idea how to make windows boot again? (**without reinstalling Windows**)

Answer (score 0):

Just switch back to IDE mode, and it should boot up again. Switching between the two is not always easy, you can read more in the many guides out there, or for example in [this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/225189/can-i-change-from-bios-ide-mode-to-ahci-mode-at-any-time?rq=1).